# Filter one table based on values from another table column

Tags: mysql, compare, comparison, multiple-columns

I have a table "PackagingType" with 2 columns (materialID | name) and another table "materials" with ID and material details.

For each name from the "packagingtype" I want to assign what materials are available (e.g. in material ID column I would have 1,3,4,5).

I need to match these materialsID with materials table and pull out the details.

What would be the correct way to do it? Not sure if storing data as 1,3,4,5 is the right was and what would be the syntax look like?

Comment: Read up on Joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 2):

In relational database design you don't combine values into one cell.  There are exceptions but are few and far between.  This would would not be normalized data and would make future query and analysis difficult/complex.  So the PackagingType should have the same name multiple times for different materialIDs.

So the table would have data like

```
MaterialID Name
1          PackageA
3          PackageA
4          PackageA
5          PackageA
```

Then to get results with the material description you'd simply do a join.

```
SELECT PT.MaterialID, PT.Name, M.Detail
FROM PackagingType PT
INNER JOIN Materials M
 on PT.MaterialID = M.MaterialID
```